# SQL outputs all rows instead of matching where condition

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm writing this MySQL query where it is supposed to select people in contacts table with a field matching a value on contacts_custom_field table. But for some reason, this query just outputs all the records. Where am I going wrong?

Current query:

```
   SELECT DISTINCT firstname
                 , lastname
                 , company_name
                 , email 
              FROM contacts_custom_field
                 , contacts 
              LEFT 
              JOIN companies companies_j 
                ON companies_j.company_id = contactdetails.company_id 
             WHERE contacts_custom_field.cf_864 = 'sales_person';
```

Comment: Don't use implicit join syntax - and definitely don't use it in conjuntion with explicit join syntax

Comment: Your query makes no sense.  You have table aliases that are not in the `FROM` clause and bad `JOIN` syntax.  Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: This is just how a LEFT JOIN exactly works

Comment: What is the condition for joining `contacts_custom_field` with `contacts`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that `contacts_custom_field` contains a column to join it with contacts table. The query could be written as:

```sql
SELECT firstname
     , lastname
     , company_name
     , email 
FROM contacts
INNER JOIN contacts_custom_field ON contacts.contact_id  = contacts_custom_field.contact_id
LEFT  JOIN companies             ON contacts.company_id  = companies.company_id
WHERE contacts_custom_field.cf_864 = 'sales_person'
```